# Run selenium grid test in 2 browsers on one machine (Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: java, selenium

I have few tests, i want to run the tests on both Chrome and firefox.

How can i do that?

My code is:

```java
@Test   //Test1
public  void logInFaildTest() {
    GridTest gridTest = new GridTest();
    WebDriver webDriver = gridTest.getWebDriver();//get driver 
    LoginPage logIn = new LoginPage(webDriver, url);
    String userName = "user";
    String pass="pass";
    ...
    webDriver.close();
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for wanting to run them both at the same time, instead of two separate tests?

Comment: Actually no, they can run at different times, but i want to run all the tests on both Chrome and Firefox, and may be on other browser in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xml file, testing.xml with the desired parameters and add a Parameters annotation (@Parameters) over your loginfailed method. That would pass all the desired parameters required for your tests

Your testing.xml might look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" >

<test name="ChromeTest">

<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />

<classes>

<class name="<your class name here>">

</class>

</classes>

</test>

<test name="FirefoxTest">

<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />

<classes>

<class name="<Your class name here>">

</class>

</classes>

</test>

<test name="IETest">

<parameter name="browser" value="IE" />

<classes>

<class name="<Your class name here>">

</class>

</classes>

</test>

</suite>
```

The above xml runs tests in parallel threads across all the three given browsers. In your java code, you should pass the parameters from testing.xml like

```
@Parameters("browser")
```

Comment: I use selenium grid, but how to mange/config that all tests run on both browser, and if there is any way to run the test at the same time(each test in different browser)?

Comment: @Alexbelenko have edited my answer, this is how i implement parallel cross browser testing. :)

Comment: Thank you, but in your solution i must add new classes to the pom file all the times, did there is a more sample way?

Comment: @Alexbelenko using an xml file is more cleaner